# Who has the strategy of winning?

Tags: combinatorics

We have $25$ cards numbered from $1$ to $25$. The first person raises a card and the second one says who is going to get the card. After that, the person that has more cards will raise the card and the other person should choose. If the cards are tied, the first person raises the next card.

The game is over when all $25$ cards have been assigned.  The winner is the person with the higher score.  (Draws are not possible, since $1+2+\cdots+25=325$ is odd.)

> Who has the strategy of winning, the first person or the second
>   person?

It seems to be a hard question I don't get to an answer, and I have no idea how to solve it. Can you help me?

Note that the person that has more cards starts not the person with higher score.

Comment: do we get to chose the card we raise?

Comment: If the other person choose us we will get it but if not he will get it himself.

Comment: No, I mean do we select the card that we raise? or is it random?

Comment: @Carry on Smiling We select it

Comment: What if the scores are equal?

Comment: Then the player that started the game will raise the card.

Comment: A good idea for thinking about problems like this is to replace the "large" number $25$ with a smaller number $n$.  Obviously if $n=1$, then the second player wins.  The second player also wins if $n=2$.  If $n=3$, however, the first player can force at least a draw by raising the $3$.

Comment: @joriki, I've edited the question to include the OP's reply to your comment.  I also added what I took to be tacit rules regarding when the game ends and how the winner is determined.